# Localization in ws02 api store

Tags: localization, wso2-api-manager, wso2

I was trying the localization feature in wso2 : 
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Adding+Internationalization+and+Localization

As per my understanding, Spanish locale is also shipped in the product so to render the api store or publisher in Spanish, all I would need to do is change browser language to Spanish?

Comment: yes you just need to change the locale of the browser

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. I opened Google Chrome > Advanced settings and changed the language to Spanish. I restarted the api manager but I still see everything in english i.e. Name, Context etc.

Comment: Hi Thusitha Thilina Dayaratne,